# OS.RENAME - Problem with double/quadruple slashes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to rename a file and am successful in doing so until the last line below. Using os.rename, no matter what I've tried (f strings for example) I just can't get it to work. I'm getting quadruple and double slashes in the output. I'm sure it's a simple resolution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import os
from os import path
import shutil
from datetime import date

WDPath = r'\\xxx\yyy\gis\SAP_IMPORT_SQLARCGIS'

ARCHIVE_PATH = r'\\xxx\yyy\gis\SAP_IMPORT_SQLARCGIS\ARCHIVE\GISDEVICES'

IMPORT_FILE_NAME = r'\GISDEVICES.txt'

IMPORT_FILE = os.path.join(f'{WDPath}{IMPORT_FILE_NAME}')
print(IMPORT_FILE, '\n')

# split the file into filename and extension
filename, extension = os.path.splitext(IMPORT_FILE_NAME)
print(filename, extension, '\n')
    
# Get the create time of the file
create_time = os.path.getctime(IMPORT_FILE)
print(create_time, '\n')

# get the readable timestamp format 
## format_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(create_time)
format_time = date.fromtimestamp(create_time)
print(format_time, '\n')

# convert time into string
format_time_string = format_time.strftime("-%Y-%m-%d")
print(format_time_string, '\n')

# Contruct the new name of the file
newfile = filename + format_time_string + extension
print(newfile, '\n')
    
# rename the file
os.rename(IMPORT_FILE, newfile)
print(IMPORT_FILE)
```

**RESULT >>**

```
\\nasgriver\SAP_Share\gis\SAP_IMPORT_SQLARCGIS\GISDEVICES.txt 

\GISDEVICES .txt 

1614332702.039849 

2021-02-26 

-2021-02-26 

\GISDEVICES-2021-02-26.txt 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\xxx\yyy\gis\SAP_IMPORT_SQLARCGIS\MOVERENAMEFILE.py", line 42, in <module>
    os.rename(IMPORT_FILE, newfile)
OSError: [WinError 17] The system cannot move the file to a different disk drive: '\\\\xxx\\yyy\\gis\\SAP_IMPORT_SQLARCGIS\\GISDEVICES.txt' -> '\\GISDEVICES-2021-02-26.txt'
```

Comment: If this is windows, then you need `\\.`, a dot after the double slashes. In Python in general, `r"\\"` is equivalent to `"\\\\"`, so becareful while using the `r` prefix.

Comment: And in general, when you want to manipulate paths, consider using the dedicated stdlib library [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

Comment: Thanks but my understanding is that r"\\" is raw and DOES NOT produce "\\\\".

Comment: In any event, I really just need the correct syntax for os.rename given the script above. This snippet is going to be inserted into and existing script, so I do not want to change the format of the already established variables.

Comment: @Dennis don't forget to mark the answer as valid if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Using the `path` submodule of `os` can come with some annoyance, you can try with `pathlib` instead:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import shutil
from datetime import date

WDPath = Path(r"\\xxx\yyy\gis\SAP_IMPORT_SQLARCGIS")

ARCHIVE_PATH = Path(r"\\xxx\yyy\gis\SAP_IMPORT_SQLARCGIS\ARCHIVE)\GISDEVICES")

IMPORT_FILE_NAME = "GISDEVICES.txt"

IMPORT_FILE = WDPath / IMPORT_FILE_NAME

print(IMPORT_FILE, '\n')

# split the file into filename and extension
filename, extension = os.path.splitext(IMPORT_FILE_NAME)
print(filename, extension, '\n')
    
# Get the create time of the file
create_time = os.path.getctime(IMPORT_FILE)
print(create_time, '\n')

# get the readable timestamp format 
## format_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(create_time)
format_time = date.fromtimestamp(create_time)
print(format_time, '\n')

# convert time into string
format_time_string = format_time.strftime("-%Y-%m-%d")
print(format_time_string, '\n')

# Contruct the new name of the file
newfile = filename + format_time_string + extension
print(newfile, '\n')

# rename the file
IMPORT_FILE.rename(IMPORT_FILE / newfile)

print(IMPORT_FILE)
```